# Strange values whilst using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a function create_plot_data(xmin, xmax, n) that produces a list (xs) of values based on the equation:
[image: equation]

This is the code I came up with:

```
def create_plot_data(xmin, xmax, n):
    xs = [xmin + i * ((xmax - xmin) / n - 1) for i in range(n)]
    return xs
```

but when I test it with:

```
create_plot_data(0, 2, 5)
```

I get:

```
[0.0, -0.6, -1.2, -1.7999999999999998, -2.4]
```

Whereas, I know I should be getting (calculated manually):

```
[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed some parens: `... + i * ((xmax - xmin) /   (  n - 1  )  )`.

Comment: Ahhh that was a silly mistake, thanks!!

Comment: I always want to have the same mistakes, not deeper :-).